# Слова, образованные способом слияния

Tags: морфемы

Отметьте правильный ответ, определив слова, образованные способом слияния (сращения).

> -Златокованый, тяжелораненый, сероглазый, правобережный, многообещающий, высокоразвитый

Comment: > способом влияния

Это какой-то новый способ:)))

Comment: Думаю, что это автокорректор не знал слово "слияние", вставил то, что было в его лексиконе - "влияние" :)  Мой тоже втихаря вставляет своё, совсем не то, что я хочу написать.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, способом слияния образованы слова "тяжелораненый, многообещающий, высокоразвитый"